# How to post a file with key parameter in Java?

Tags: java, file-upload, http-post

Hello I do not know too much about HTTP Post. I need to post a file to url as key,value pair. Example :

```
key = "logFile", value = fileToUpdate
```

I tried to learn from google and I came up with this code :

```
 try {
        File filePost = new File("C:/Users/harun.acar/IdeaProjects/RaspBerryTest/540624d27037e20e3829cc03-136_rows-5ac490bf.bin");
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url+"?"+params);
        MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        entity.addPart("file",new FileBody(filePost));
        httpPost.setEntity(entity.build());
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        System.out.println(responseStr);

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

But I need to specify the key parameter but I do not know how to put this in entry( or if I need to  put it in somewhere else) Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the key with this line:

```
entity.addPart("file",new FileBody(filePost));
```

You have to change the string `"file"` with `"logFile"`

You can also call this method without use the `FileBody` class

```
entity.addBinaryBody("logFile", filePost);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Add your data  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "12312"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sessionid", "234"));  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  



public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/myexample.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "stackoverflow.com is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```